# concat 2 different image size multiple tracks videos

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I try concat two videos (1.mkv has 640:360 image size, 2.mkv has 1280:720 image size), both videos have 2 video tracks and 0 audio tracks. I tried this code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[0:v:1]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[v0][1:v:0][1:v:1]concat=n=2:v=2:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v "libvpx" 1+2.mkv
```

But I have wrong:

```
Filter pad has an unconnected output
```

Answer (score 0):

Your filter labels need to be adjusted, and you need to change `v=2` to `v=1` in concat filter:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v:0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libvpx 1+2.mkv
```

Since `2.mkv` is already 1280x720 you can avoid processing that input:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -i 2.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v:0]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[v0][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libvpx 1+2.mkv
```